# Error: Could not find or load main class concurrency.MainTest

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error

I installed eclipse kepler and JDK 1.7.45 on lubuntu 13.04

Here is java version:

```
nazar@nazar-desktop:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
nazar@nazar-desktop:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_45
```

I configured at eclipse at:

> Window => preferences => java => installed jre => add my jdk

I wrote easy test class:

```
package concurrency;

public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world ");
    }    
}
```

But when I run I see error message:

> Error: Could not find or load main class concurrency.MainTest

It even doesn't compile this class into `src/bin`.

I tried to do it by myself as

> javac MainTest.java => java MainTest

It compiles but at run time throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MainTest (wrong name: concurrency/MainTest)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I couldn't figure out what it can be. Coz installed jdk is compatible with OS system.

UPDATE:

This project was from another machine there was installed `java.1.7_40`.
Here I imported this project and keep doing it.

Here is content of `eclipse.ini`:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
```

Any suggestions?

- ***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: As a side note. Quote: "*It even doesn't compile this class into src/bin.*" Actually it should be just **bin**. Traditionally the *src* folder is for the source code, *bin* for the compiled code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really made it clear what you've done in Eclipse, but we can easily fix the "compiling and running it from the command line" problem. You're compiling and running it from the wrong directory. Compile it from the root, either like this:

```
$ javac concurrency/MainTest.java
$ java concurrency.MainTest
```

or use `-d` to specify an output directory:

```
$ javac -d bin concurrency/MainTest.java
$ java -cp bin concurrency.MainTest
```

Comment: @nazar_art: You haven't told us anything about what you've done in Eclipse - we don't know whether you've set up the right project type, what your settings are like etc. It's hard to help with so little information.

Comment: @nazar_art: Well that's the Eclipse launcher settings - but nothing about your project. We don't know what you've got set up as source directories, output directories, compile-on-save etc. Is there *any* trace of class files written by Eclipse? If you deliberately introduce an error, does that produce an error message in the Eclipse error list?

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I found cause of trouble. It was two jar files from old build pass.

Comment: It's so easy to check it at Eclipse. Just right click on your project and select Java Build Path. Once there, check the Source tab and they will appear the folders that are being compiled; if you see your java file as Excluded fix it (right click on Excluded class and remove it) or, if your java's folder is not a Source Folder, click on the right Add Folder's button and and it.